# not supported between instances of 'AnsibleUnsafeText' and 'int'

Tags: ansible, condition

Пытаюсь запустить код в ansible получаю ошибку! Как можно ее решить?

### Playbook

```
---
- name: "Проверяем свободное место"
  shell: "df / --output=avail|tail -1"
  register: avail_size
- set_fact:
    free_fs_size: "{{ avail_size.stdout|int }}"


- name: "Запускаем создание резервной копиии средствами php"
  shell: '{{ make_backup }}'
  register: result
  when: "{{ free_fs_size > 10 }}"
  failed_when: "'The backup was incorrect and it was deleted' in result.stdout_lines"
- set_fact:
    backup_path: "{{result.stdout_lines | regex_search(regexp, '\\2')}}"
    vars:
      regexp: '(Backup started to file: )(.*)"'
```

### Error

````yaml
[WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: {{ free_fs_size > 10 }}
fatal: [host.dev.domain.ru]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check '{{ free_fs_size > 10 }}' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ free_fs_size > 10 }}): '>' not supported between instances of 'AnsibleUnsafeText' and 'int'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/opt/ansible/roles/backup_bitrix/tasks/main.yml': line 9, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: \"Запускаем создание резервной копиии средствами php\"\n  ^ here\n"}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам отвечаю:

когда устанавливается факт:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    free_fs_size: "{{ avail_size.stdout|int }}"
```

Он является строковым значением, т.к. |int - это фильтр, который не преобразует выражение, а просто проверяет. По идее его можно вообще тут не писать.

Решением является следующий код:

```yaml
- name: "Запускаем создание резервной копиии средствами php"
  shell: '{{ make_backup }}'
  register: result
  when: free_fs_size | int >  1024000
```